# YADCF range_number - is it possible to add a preset select list to to/from range?

Tags: yadcf

I want to add a select list to to/from fields of range_number so user can pick from set amounts to set range.

Answer (score 0):

best option would be to use the custom function filtering `filter_type: 'custom_func'`

[see showcase, first column](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source.html) , code sample and everything can be found on that page

```
{
    column_number: 0,
    filter_type: 'custom_func',
    custom_func: myCustomFilterFunction,
```

...

(possible) custom func implementation

```
function myCustomFilterFunction(filterVal, columnVal) {
    var found;
    if (columnVal === '') {
        return true;
    }
    switch (filterVal) {
    case 'happy':
        found = columnVal.search(/:-\]|:\)|Happy|JOY|:D/g);
        break;
    case 'sad':
        found = columnVal.search(/:\(|Sad|:'\(/g);
        break;
    case 'angry':
        found = columnVal.search(/!!!|Arr\.\.\./g);
        break;
    case 'lucky':
        found = columnVal.search(/777|Bingo/g);
        break;
    case 'january':
        found = columnVal.search(/01|Jan/g);
        break;
    default:
        found = 1;
        break;
    }

    if (found !== -1) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```